# breeze.js one to many

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I'm currently building an SPA with Web API and knockout etc. So far i worte my own simple datacontext and it worked pretty well. 
The I bumped in to breeze and thought it might be worth a try. especially I hoped to get a simpler approach on navigation between the entities...

to load a entities or a single entity with breeze worked fine. Working with navigation properties seems not to work. The navigation property is always empty, even though it's a one to many relationship.

Here is my model (simplified):

```
public class WorkdayHours
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsWorkDay { get; set; }
    ...
    public Byte WeekDay { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkdayHours> BookableDays { get; set; }
}
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkdayHours> BookableDays { get; set; }
}
public class Shop
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkdayHours> BookableDays { get; set; }
}
```

Then I fetch the entity service ind my SPA as follow:

```
var query = EntityQuery
            .from('Services')   
            .where('id', 'eq', serviceId)
            .expand('BookableDays');
```

As when teh query is executed I get as result the requested service entity with all the data except the bookableDay property is always an empty array.
When I check the Json answer I see that also the workdayHours are transmitted and breeze even calls my defined ctors for this entities. However they are not linked to the bookableDays property itself.

When checking the genrated DB model, EF generated foreignkeys for service, employee and shop in workdayHours as expected.

Is breeze not capable with having several optional foreignkeys?

Suggestion and ideas highly apprechiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breeze is dependent on Foreign Keys. I had a similar problem. This should solve it:
EF was generating the ForeignKeys for me too and the related Entites where still empty. As far as i know breeze needs the explicit Annotation/Configuration of ForeignKey Fields.

```
public class Mvl
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long MvlId{ get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Mvl")]
    public ICollection<MvlOP> MvlOps { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ReleasedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LockedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ClosedAt { get; set; }

    //[ConcurrencyCheck]
    //public int? RowVersion { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

public class MvlOP
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long MvlOpId { get; set; }


    public long MvlId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MvlId")]
    public Mvl Mvl { get; set; }

...
}
```

Comment: Hi Sascha thank you for the feedback. I tired it out an run into another issue. I got now a exception from the Json serializer about circual references... After changing the settings of the serialiser to `json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;` it worked.

Comment: I'm curious about this because PreserveReferencesHandling.Object is the default in BreezeConfig.  These defaults are applied if you use the BreezeControllerAttribute on your ApiController subclass.

Comment: My contoller code looks pretty much as in your samples... at least that what I belive ;-) `[BreezeController]    public class BreezeController : ApiController` my global config looks like `public static void CustomizeConfig(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
 return Json.
   config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);` see next comment

Comment: `var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter; json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
json.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
json.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
IsoDateTimeConverter iso = new IsoDateTimeConverter(); 
iso.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffK";
json.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(iso);
config.Filters.Add(new ValidationActionFilter());`

Comment: Don't expect the formatters you added in Global.asax (or anywhere outside the controller) to be used within the controller. The [BreezeController] attribute removes all global content formatters from the pipeline for that controller ... and then adds the Breeze JsonFormatter.

Comment: Sascha - You don't have to add FK and InverseProperty notations to the class. You can define them with the [EF Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx). I prefer that approach because it keeps my classes free of these concerns. But the attributes are handy and you may prefer them. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: One more thing. Breeze does require foreign keys if you intend the client to support navigation of related entities in cache. Identifying the proper FKs is a matter of working the correct EF magic; Breeze has no part in that.